# How to remove an 'underscore' sign from a filename?

Tags: r

I have :

```
paste("~/coefficient_rho",Sys.Date(), sep="_","/correlation.RData")
```

which gives

```
[1] "~/coefficient_rho_2019-04-30_/correlation.RData"
```

What I want to get is

```
[1] "~/coefficient_rho_2019-04-30/correlation.RData"
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `paste` / `paste0` to get what you want:

```
paste0(paste("~/coefficient_rho",Sys.Date(), sep="_"),"/correlation.RData")
[1] "~/coefficient_rho_2019-04-30/correlation.RData"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could juste write the first tabulation in the string `"~/coefficient_rho_"` and use `paste0` to paste the rest of you path without separator.

`paste0("~/coefficient_rho_", Sys.Date(), "/correlation.RData")`